# Spring REST not returing anything

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

Here is my rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

   @Autowired
   private  AppInstances appInstances;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/signup")
   public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody SignupForm form) throws Exception
   {
       ResponseEntity<?> validate = FormFieldValidator.validate(form);
       if(validate.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK)
           return validate;
       else
       {
           return SignupService.signup(form, appInstances);
       }
   }
```

Here is HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form method="post">            
            <input type="text" name="userType" value="USER"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="pwd" value="123456"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="rpwd" value="123456"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="manish kumar"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="sex" value="Male"/><br>
            <input type="text" name="bizzCategory" value="Restaurant"/><br>            
            <button>OK</button>
        </form>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var formData = $("form").serializeArray();
    var jsonData={};
    $(formData).each(function(i,o){
     console.log(o.name+"==="+o.value);
     jsonData[o.name] = o.value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8084/mobapp/signup",
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    }).done(function(d){
        alert(JSON.stringify(d));
    }).error(function(e){
        alert(e);
    });
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what it shows in firebug. It has no response by the way.

`OPTIONS signup         200 OK        localhost:8084`

I a using spring security 4.0.1.

Comment: Is you are controller getting called ?

Comment: As you can see the request is sent using the method `OPTIONS`. I guess you make a cross-domain request.

Comment: `OPTIONS` does not have a response body, what's in it's headers? and is your javascript running on localhost:8084?